# Screenshot: take picture of current monitor/current window only in 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of only active screen, or ideally only the active window. I am happy to use  a specific combination of keys to do it, although ideal would be to set this as default.

According to the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html), it is possible to do this using `Alt+Print Screen`. This does not seem to work with Ubuntu 20.04: I get a shot of my two screens. Is there something wrong on my side, or is the documentation not updated?

Second, I tried to set this by default in `dconf`: `org/gnome/gnome-screenshot`. I see there is a take-window-shot option, but it seems deprecated? Why would they deprecate that? Is there no other option? Or should I look for an alternative screenshot utility?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PRT SC</kbd> is the correct shortcut to take a screenshot of the active window.

The screenshot is automatically saved in `~/Pictures`

I just confirmed this using Ubuntu 20.04.1 in a liveUSB session (GNOME).

Comment: thanks for checking! And what about making this the default behaviour?

Comment: It already is the default behavior. I'm not sure why yours is different. It can be easily adjusted in the "Keyboard Shortcuts" menu in Settings. The other answer explains how to do this in great detail, but to simplify= find the shortcut you want to change, click it, and enter the keys you wish to use for the shortcut you selected

Answer (score 1):

The default button for screenshot can be checked in settings. Press `super key` (`windows` button on PC or `command` button on mac), and type `shortcut` and select keyboard shortcuts.

Start typing `screenshot` and shortcuts related to screenshots will appear in front of you.

If you want to enable custom shortcuts, then erase the `screenshot` typed earlier and scroll down to bottom and click the `plus` sign at the very bottom. For the name field enter `screenshot full` (or whatever you wish to name it) and in the command section type `gnome-screenshot` and click on the `set shortcut` and press the key combination you want to take screenshot of the whole screen.

If you want to take screenshot of an area which you want to select (a crosshair will appear and then you have to press and drag to select an area and screenshot will be taken of this area only), then instead of just `gnome-screenshot` type `gnome-screenshot -a` and then select the key combination you want.

If you use `gnome-screenshot -w` in the `command` field then it will take the screenshot of the current windows which is highlighted.

All these screenshot will be saved to the `Pictures` folder in the home directory.

Just as we used `-a` and `-w` at the end of `gnome-screenshot` command, there are several others called as flags. Open terminal and type `gnome-screenshot -h` and this will display all the available flags.